# JAXB Unmarshalling Entities - References null

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have 2 mapping classes (analogue to JPA classes):

**AElement.java**

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "children", })
@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class AElement implements Serializable {

 private String name;
 private List<BElement> children;

 @XmlElement(name = "metadatum")
 public List<BElement> getChildren(){
    return children;
 }

 ...
}
```

**BElement.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "b")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name"})
public class BElement implements Serializable{

 private String name;
 private AElement parent;

 ...
}
```

A and B are in a *OneToMany* relation. The XML should look like this:

```
<A>
  <B></B>
  <B></B>
</A>
```

If I unmarshal the xml, map it to my JPA classes and persist it to my database everything is 
stored correctly **except** my references. This means that `B` is stored without a foreign key to `A` in the database.

I'm using JPA with Hibernate. Following my JPA classes:

**A.java**

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {


 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long id;

 @Column
 private String name;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
 private List<B> children;

 public List<B> getChildren(){
    return children;
 }

 ...
}
```

**B.java**

```
@Entity
public class B implements Serializable{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long id;

 @Column
 private String name;

 @ManyToOne(optional = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private A parent;

 ...
}
```

Comment: I think that you should add more information about the persistence, seems a JPA issue.

Comment: Are you sure that exist In the B table the column `a_id`? Anyway for the `@ManyToOne` `optional = true` ain't necessary because is its default value, and you can remove also `referencedColumnName = "id"` on JoinColumn.

Comment: Yes, there is a colum a_id. I hava a webclient for inserting data and I'm trying to add export/import functionality. So I think the problem is associated with the unmarshalling.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. the problem is the unmarshal. When read the xml, in the object B doesn't put the reference to A. To persit correctly a bidirectional relationship you must add in both side the objects. In few words, when you try to persist in the instances of B there isn't the referenct to A.

Comment: Some more information: I'm doing the mapping via DOZER. So every value of every field of the mapping class is being mapped to the jpa class. After that, I get the same values in the JPA class (also all B entries). Then, I'm calling my persist function. Taking a look in the database and the a_id column is NULL.

Comment: You may find the following helpful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to assign the appropriate A to each B. This solves my problem.

```
a.getB().forEach(b -> b.setA(a));
```

I don't know If it is a good workaround? Especially because I have other entities that are children of `B`.

Comment: Isn't workaround but is a correct way to persist a bidirectional relationship. As i say above in previous comment. Dozer didn't set the relationship in both side.

Comment: Anyway is really necessary the bidirectionality of all your relationships? .. If you remove it (e.g. @ManyToOne from B) all works fine (without above solution).

Comment: Yes, I need them bi-directional. Is there a way to map bi-directional with DOZER?

Comment: Your first problem is that JAXB does not set A reference inside B. If you get this way I think that you could have a problem about a cyclic reference when you try to marshal A. Anyway try with `<a>this</A>`.

Comment: What do you mean by <a>this</A>?

Comment: Dozer mapping xml ... Do you use it?

Comment: Depends, Dozer don't need of xml mapping, he works by reflection and field name. You should use the mapping only to change default behaviour. In our case Dozer set A into B, but he set null because into BElement the field AElement is null, so to change it we must use the XML mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Method `afterUnmarshal` in class **BElement.java**

```
public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
   this.a = (AElement)parent;
}
```